# ffmpeg - why does hstack fail with " width not divisible by 2" When both of my inputs have even heights?

Tags: ffmpeg

Here's the command I'm using to horizontally stack 2 mp4's together:

`ffmpeg -y  -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]hstack[v]" -map "[v]" -vsync 0 stacked.mp4`

input1.mp4 has dimensions 594x512, and input2.mp4 has dimensions 512x512. I get this error in return:

```
width not divisible by 2 (1113x512)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

The confusing thing is that 1113 is such an odd number - it is not 1024, and not even 512+594 (1106). What is causing the assumed width to be such a strange value?

Comment: Need to see the complete log from the command.

Comment: @llogan here you go! https://pastebin.com/kV2BtXmJ

Comment: Your inputs are 512x512 and 601x512.

Comment: Both video heights are 512 according to the properties --> details tab. The only mismatching dimension is width, which is shown to be 594. Can you explain why 601 seems to be the assumed height? Is ffmpeg resizing the video?

Comment: I'm simply looking at the properties menu when right clicking the file, then navigating to the details tab.

Comment: Windows Explorer

Answer (score 0):

Windows Explorer is incorrect. It does not properly support yuvj444p, so it is giving a wrong width.